# Twitter Bootstrap Navbar Causing Bookmarks Not To Work

Tags: wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I am experiencing a very strange phenomenon with Bootstrap.  Whenever I enable the navbar, which I only use for tablets and below, bookmarks cease to work.  This may be related to [another problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18070800/bootstrap-navbar-conflict-with-scrollspy) I had earlier in which I couldn't get scrollspy to work while navbar was being included in the page.

I am completely clueless, and I have been trying everything under the sun to figure this out.
I have used the bootstrap docs to emulate how the navbar is supposed to be used, and I am still getting this conflict.  However, the second I take out the navbar, bookmarks start to work again.

I know for a fact that the navbar can indeed work with scrollspy because they have it working on their docs page.  At this point I have given up on scrollspy, but would at least like my bookmarks to work.  The menu on the right side of page should bookmark to different divs in the page.

Here's a link to the page in question: http://tinyurl.com/q7ocdz4

I don't know, at this point any insights would be welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading your symptoms it was obvious that the problem was with duplicate ids on your elements, after checking your website markup I confirmed it, you used the same id attributes from your content in your affix nav list items, I don't think the ids in the  affix are actually needed so just remove them and you should be fine.

```
/*Remove the ids from the affix nav*/
<li id="biblical-studies"></li>
<li id="career-discipleship"></li>
<li id="discipleship-training-schools"></li>
<li id="secondary-schools"></li>
<li id="seminars"></li>
<li id="summer-programs"></li>
```

Comment: Hey, thanks so much for the reply, I have removed the duplicate IDs and still get the same behavior.  I realized that I had the mobile navbar disabled, so I have re-enabled it for testing purposes.  I have checked and can't find any duplicate IDs anywhere else.

Comment: Scratch that, there was another duplicate.  Thanks so much for your help.